# How do I check if the archive has only one folder in python?

Tags: python, django, zip, archive, tar

I am trying to upload a file(which can be one of tar,tar.gz,bz2 or zip) and before uploading it, I want to check that the contents of the tar (or any compressed format) has only folder at the top with a name same as that of the variable 'name'.

In my code, I am able to upload the file but I am not able to check the above condition. Please note that getnames() in the code does not work. How do we check that there is only one folder at the top with a given name?

Please note that the folders may have no files inside them. The folders may be empty.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
with Archive(fileobj=data['zxc']) as archive:
    if archive.is_archive():
       count=0
       nam=""
       for a in (get names of folders at the top):
           nam=""
           count+=1
           if count!=1:
               print "error"
           elif nam!=name:
               print "error2"
           else:
               print "correct"
```

Comment: What is utils.archives? It does not seem like a standard python library. Where is it documented?

Comment: It is here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/archive.py

Answer (score 0):

The docs lead me to believe this is your recourse, but I do not think 'zxc' files are supported by the archive class in django.

```
def has_leading_dir(self, paths):
    """
    Returns true if all the paths have the same leading path name
    (i.e., everything is in one subdirectory in an archive)
    """
    common_prefix = None
    for path in paths:
        prefix, rest = self.split_leading_dir(path)
        if not prefix:
            return False
        elif common_prefix is None:
            common_prefix = prefix
        elif prefix != common_prefix:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: zxc is a variable's name and not a filename and it works. What I am asking in the question is how to impement the pseudocode mentioned in the question in python.

Comment: has_leading_dir may not work if there is an extra folder at the top with no contents